# Cordova iOS simulator only shows 320px (my content is 640px)

Tags: html, css, iphone, cordova

nothing found in the www about my problem. I have a content of 640px filled with divs and images. If i run my app on the iPhone Simulator now, it only shows 320px and cuts the half of the content.

This is my header:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum- scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/stylesheet.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/iscroll.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var myScroll;
    function loaded () {
        myScroll = new IScroll('#wrapper', { useTransition: false });
    }
        document.addEventListener('touchmove', function (e) {  e.preventDefault(); }, false);
</script>
```

And here a link to my Stylesheet (i hope this is okay?!)
http://pastebin.com/1CDxMLHW

Hope u can tell my, what i did wrong!

Comment: What happens when you set a width to the body. The body now has overflow:hidden. This can be the problem since the overflow is cut off

Comment: Didn't change anything... i made a screenshot for u :-/

http://abload.de/img/iossimulatorbildschir9vkdj.png

Comment: Not sure if this is way you want. But it is better to work with % instead of px so that your lay-out is flexible. In this way the elements adapt to the screen size. with media queries you can even optimize this further.

Comment: No it is not, but thank u! :-/

I set the width to 100% now but nothing changes...i realy don't know why my simulator (ios 7.1 retina 3.5Inch) only shows me 320px or why he is scaling the whole index to 150% :-/!

Comment: Okay i just found out, that i have to name the pictures with @2x.png at the end for Retina resolution. But... now it shows me not an only image... ._.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is is that the emulator is not realy retina it depends on your own screen. I have reproduces the problem and solved the problem by making your lay out fluid. The width of all elements are defined with percentages. In this way they can adapt to the available screen width.

```
/*########################
# GENERAL SCROLL STYLING #
########################*/
html {
        -ms-touch-action: none;
        width: 100%;
}

li, ul{
        list-style: none;
        padding: 0;
}

body {
        overflow: hidden; /* this is important to prevent the whole page to bounce */
}

#header {
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 2;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 118px;
        padding: 0;
        border-top: 18px solid #000000;
}

#footer {
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 2;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 48px;
        background: #444;
        padding: 0;
        border-top: 1px solid #444;
}

#wrapper {
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 1;
        top: 45px;
        bottom: 48px;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        overflow: hidden;
        -webkit-touch-callout: none;
        -webkit-user-select: none;
        -moz-user-select: none;
        -ms-user-select: none;
        user-select: none;
        -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
        -moz-text-size-adjust: none;
        -ms-text-size-adjust: none;
        -o-text-size-adjust: none;
        text-size-adjust: none;
}

#scroller {
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 1;
        -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
        width: 100%;
        -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
        -moz-transform: translateZ(0);
        -ms-transform: translateZ(0);
        -o-transform: translateZ(0);
        transform: translateZ(0);
}

/*########################
# GENERAL HEAD STYLING   #
########################*/

.head_first{
        background:url(../img/buttons/fb_btn.png);
        width: 30%;
        height: 100px;
        float: left;
}

.head_second{
        background:url(../img/buttons/nav_top_btn.png);
        width: 30%;
        height: 100px;
        float: left;
}

.head_third{
        background:url(../img/buttons/weather_btn.png);
        width: 30%;
        height: 100px;
        float: left;
}

#main_pic{
        background:url(../img/start/strand.jpg);
        width: 100%;
        height: 400px;
        clear: both;
        float: left;
        margin-top: 73px;
}

/*########################
# CONTENT      STYLING   #
########################*/

li{
        background:url(../img/buttons/nav_btn.png);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        list-style: none;
        clear: both;
        float: left;
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        height: 64px;
        color: #FFFFFF;
        font-size: 35px;
}

li a{
        top: 10px;
        left: 20px;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        display: block;
        position: relative;
}

a:link{
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #FFFFFF;
}

a:hover{
        text-decoration: none;
}

a:active{
        text-decoration: none;
}

a:visited{
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #FFFFFF;
}

/*########################
# FOOTER       STYLING   #
########################*/

.footer_first{
        background:url(../img/buttons/home_btn.png);
        clear: both;
        float: left;
        width: 25%;
        height: 84px;
}

.footer_second{
        background:url(../img/buttons/news_btn.png);
        float: left;
        width: 25%;
        height: 84px;
}

.footer_third{
        background:url(../img/buttons/card_btn.png);
        float: left;
        width: 25%;
        height: 84px;
}

.footer_fourth{
        background:url(../img/buttons/faehr_btn.png);
        float: left;
        width: 25%;
        height: 84px;

}
```